# not able to create directory as well as file in java

Tags: java

I wanted to create a file in a directory, using below code:

```
import java.io.*;

class Test2 {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

    File f = new File("D:\\docs\\voucherList_cinthol_2018-04-25 11-46-29.csv");

    System.out.println(f.createNewFile());


    }

}
```

here, `docs` directory is not there in `d:` drive. so I wanted both directory and file to be created.
I am getting below exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.wpits.acf.utils.Test2.main(Test2.java:14)
```

How can I resolve this problem, please suggest

Comment: try to use f.getParentFile().mkdirs() before

Answer (score 0):

You can use guava to handle this.

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#createParentDirs-java.io.File-

This ensures that the target file gets created even if embedded in a deep hierarchy of directories.

Comment: Adding Guava just for this is overkill.